# GUI Internet Meter for Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, mobile-broadband

Is there any GUI app that can work as an internet/**data meter** (not internet speed-meter) on **Xubuntu** 16.04? Would be better if it can show upload/download speed on the panel too. Ubuntu (Unity) has [**Indicator Netspeed**](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/indicator-netspeed-displays-network.html)
which worked ok but it doesn't work on Xubuntu.
I am aware that there is a built in panel applet named **Network Monitor** in Xubuntu. But it can only act as a badly designed speed-meter. I use metered data plans and I need to constantly keep an eye on data usage. Terminal apps like **vnstat** isn't doing the job for me.

Comment: I think [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) can do this. I'm not sure, but it can monitor and analyze all network traffic.

Comment: I don't need an package analyzer. I just need a GUI app which will keep track of my data usage(so I don't cross my daily cap).:-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nino is what you are looking for.
install it from the software center

Comment: Wow, an answer after 2.5 years! Thanks! Though I can't test it now but it seems like it'll work.

Comment: Well i was looking for something similar and ended up here.